# TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000] after loading "hanging module" in both parent and child documents in LyX Classicthesis

Tags: errors, lyx, classicthesis, capacity

I use classicthesis-LyX-v4.2_biblatex_bibtex8

I got this error message when I load hanging module into the parent document (probably my personal issue, as I tried it on the newly downloaded template, there was no such message)
Error description: "If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me."

Action 1:

If I remove

1. the child document bibliography.lyx, which contains all references (I don't have time to use database, so I just copied the endnote reference list from word) converted from standard environment to hanging environment (by loading hanging module)
2. the hanging module

from the parent document (classicthesis), then everything is back to normal again, no error message at all.

Action 2:

If I replace the bibliography.lyx in a newly downloaded Classicthesis template with my created bibliography.lyx, no errors at all.

Action 3:

I copied the parent document from the newly downloaded template to replace the existing one, then the same error message pops up as well.

Therefore, I presume it is caused by a clash between the created bibliography.lyx and my written chapters. Is it because my thesis has too much stuff? How to enlarge the capacity?

Comment: Did you check on this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24247/tex-capacity-exceeded-sorry-input-stack-size-5000 if there is some common points with your problem?

Comment: I forgot to mention that if I replace the bibliography.lyx in a freshly downloaded classicthesis  template with my created bibliography.lyx, no errors at all. Furthermore, there is no url in my reference list list. Thx for the information. It is likely to help me in the future.

Comment: I doubt it is possible to help much if you don't provide any real example to demonstrate the problem. The problem is unrelated to the length of your thesis (which could have tens of thousands of pages without making tex run out of memory) most likely you have a definition that is calling itself and put tex into a loop using up the input stack. As always you should post an example that demonstrates the problem. Start from a copy of your document, make it as small as possible while showing the error, export it to latex, and post the code into your question.

Comment: I will do this after thesis submission, which is due next Thursday. As an emergency plan, if  no simple solution is available, I will just generate the reference pages separately and use PDF professional to combine them later.

Comment: (Following on from your earlier question.) As David says, without an example we can look at it is impossible to say what is going on. This shouldn't happen in a normal document. (I wonder if there's something in your manual reference list that shouldn't be there.) Another possibility would be to ask the LyX people if they have a discussion list on their website. Not many people use LyX around here.

Comment: Thx again. It is hard to figure out a minimal example as I don't know what stuff in my chapter causes the clash. I will try to do this after thesis submission to help people that may suffer similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [hanging package chokes on apostrophes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61732/hanging-package-chokes-on-apostrophes),

simply add 
    `\usepackage[notquote]{hanging}`
     to Document->Setting->Latex Preamble for both the parent document (that is, classicthesis.lyx) and the child document in which you want to use hanging module (for example, Bibliography.lyx) solves the problem!