# Shortcut for $ ^{\prime} $ is not working in beamer

Tags: beamer, superscripts

I am preparing some lecture notes in `beamer` documentclass. After I added quite a much of customisations, I realised that the shortcut `'` for `$ ^{\prime} $` is not working. How do I restore the usual behaviour? Following is an MWE. Please help.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,10pt, notheorems]{beamer}
\setbeamerfont{headline}{size=\fontsize{8}{0}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\fontsize{6}{0}\selectfont}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{sapphire}{rgb}{0.01, 0.01, 1}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{(\alph{enumii})}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{\arabic{enumi}.}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}
%\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\usepackage{hanging}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hanging
\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
    \hangpara{2em}{1}%
    \makebox[2em][l]{\insertfootnotemark}\footnotesize\insertfootnotetext\par%
}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=magenta}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{bg=black}

%\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage{latex2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{upgreek}


\newtagform{dots}{$ \cdots $(}{)}
\usetagform{dots}


\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple, labelsep=colon]{subcaption}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\thefigure.(\alph{subfigure})}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@subfigure{}
\makeatother


\makeatletter
\let\save@mathaccent\mathaccent
\newcommand*\if@single[3]{%
    \setbox0\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{#1}}^H$}%
    \setbox2\hbox{${\mathaccent"0362{\kern0pt#1}}^H$}%
    \ifdim\ht0=\ht2 #3\else #2\fi
}
%The bar will be moved to the right by a half of \macc@kerna, which is computed by amsmath:
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
%If there's a superscript following the bar, then no negative kern may follow the bar;
%an additional {} makes sure that the superscript is high enough in this case:
\newcommand*\widebar[1]{\@ifnextchar^{{\wide@bar{#1}{0}}}{\wide@bar{#1}{1}}}
%Use a separate algorithm for single symbols:
\newcommand*\wide@bar[2]{\if@single{#1}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{1}}{\wide@bar@{#1}{#2}{2}}}
\newcommand*\wide@bar@[3]{%
    \begingroup
    \def\mathaccent##1##2{%
        %Enable nesting of accents:
        \let\mathaccent\save@mathaccent
        %If there's more than a single symbol, use the first character instead (see below):
        \if#32 \let\macc@nucleus\first@char \fi
        %Determine the italic correction:
        \setbox\z@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}_{}$}%
        \setbox\tw@\hbox{$\macc@style{\macc@nucleus}{}_{}$}%
        \dimen@\wd\tw@
        \advance\dimen@-\wd\z@
        %Now \dimen@ is the italic correction of the symbol.
        \divide\dimen@ 3
        \@tempdima\wd\tw@
        \advance\@tempdima-\scriptspace
        %Now \@tempdima is the width of the symbol.
        \divide\@tempdima 10
        \advance\dimen@-\@tempdima
        %Now \dimen@ = (italic correction / 3) - (Breite / 10)
        \ifdim\dimen@>\z@ \dimen@0pt\fi
        %The bar will be shortened in the case \dimen@<0 !
        \rel@kern{0.6}\kern-\dimen@
        \if#31
        \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.4}\kern\dimen@}%
        \advance\dimen@0.4\dimexpr\macc@kerna
        %Place the combined final kern (-\dimen@) if it is >0 or if a superscript follows:
        \let\final@kern#2%
        \ifdim\dimen@<\z@ \let\final@kern1\fi
        \if\final@kern1 \kern-\dimen@\fi
        \else
        \overline{\rel@kern{-0.6}\kern\dimen@#1}%
        \fi
    }%
    \macc@depth\@ne
    \let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
    \mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
    \macc@set@skewchar\relax
    \let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
    %The following initialises \macc@kerna and calls \mathaccent:
    \if#31
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}%
    \else
    %If the argument consists of more than one symbol, and if the first token is
    %a letter, use that letter for the computations:
    \def\gobble@till@marker##1\endmarker{}%
    \futurelet\first@char\gobble@till@marker#1\endmarker
    \ifcat\noexpand\first@char A\else
    \def\first@char{}%
    \fi
    \macc@nested@a\relax111{\first@char}%
    \fi
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\renewcommand{\l}{\lambda}
\renewcommand{\L}{\Lambda}
\newcommand{\G}{\mathscr{G}}
\newcommand{\B}{\mathscr{B}}
\renewcommand{\d}{\delta}
\newcommand{\e}{\epsilon}
\renewcommand{\a}{\alpha}
\renewcommand{\b}{\beta}
\renewcommand{\r}{\mathrm{r}}
\newcommand{\n}{\mathrm{N}}
\newcommand{\g}{\gamma}
\renewcommand{\th}{\uptheta}
\let\emptyset\varnothing
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}
\newcommand{\ts}{\textstyle}
\newcommand{\func}[3]{#1\mathpunct{:}#2\to#3}
\newcommand{\mat}[1]{\left\llbracket #1 \right\rrbracket}
\newcommand{\scr}[1]{\mathscr{#1}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\image}{Im}
\newcommand{\comb}[2]{\begin{psmallmatrix}#1 \\ #2\end{psmallmatrix}}
\renewcommand{\limsup}{\widebar{\lim}\,}
\renewcommand{\liminf}{\underline{\lim}\,}

%\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
%\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}


\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,fg=yellow,bg=black}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment<>{proofs}[1][\proofname]{\par\def\insertproofname{\scshape #1\@addpunct{:}}\usebeamertemplate{proof begin}#2} {\usebeamertemplate{proof end}}

\newenvironment<>{proofc}{\setbeamertemplate{proof begin}{\begin{block}{}}\par\usebeamertemplate{proof begin}}  {\usebeamertemplate{proof end}}

\newenvironment<>{proofe}{\par\pushQED{\qed}\setbeamertemplate{proof begin}{\begin{block}{}}\usebeamertemplate{proof begin}}        {\popQED\usebeamertemplate{proof end}}
\makeatother
        
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment<>{proof}[1][\proofname]
{
    \par
    \def\insertproofname{\scshape #1\@addpunct{:}}%
    \usebeamertemplate{proof begin}#2
    \parskip 1ex
    \pushQED{\qed}
}
{
    \popQED\usebeamertemplate{proof end}
}
\makeatother
        
        
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]

        


%\setbeamercolor{block title proofs}{use=structure}
%\setbeamercolor{block body proofs}{parent=normal text,use=block title proof,fg=yellow,bg=black}
%
%\setbeamercolor{block title proofc}{use=structure}
%\setbeamercolor{block body proofc}{parent=normal text,use=block title proof,fg=yellow,bg=black}
%
%\setbeamercolor{block title proofe}{use=structure}
%\setbeamercolor{block body proofe}{parent=normal text,use=block title proof,fg=yellow,bg=black}



\BeforeBeginEnvironment{theorem}{
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg,bg=pink!50!white}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=pink!25!white}
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{theorem}{
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg,bg=structure.fg!20!bg}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!50!bg, fg=black}
}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{proposition}{
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg,bg=pink!40!white}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=pink!15!white}
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{proposition}{
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg,bg=structure.fg!20!bg}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!50!bg, fg=black}
}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{corollary}{
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg,bg=pink!30!white}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=pink!5!white}
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{corollary}{
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg,bg=structure.fg!20!bg}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!50!bg, fg=black}
}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{lemma}{
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg,bg=pink!30!white}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=pink!5!white}
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{lemma}{
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg,bg=structure.fg!20!bg}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!50!bg, fg=black}
}


\BeforeBeginEnvironment{definition}{%
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=red!75!black,bg=olive!40!white}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=olive!20!white}
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{definition}{
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg,bg=structure.fg!20!bg}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!50!bg, fg=black}
}

%%\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
%\setbeamercolor{proofs}{fg=black}
%\setbeamercolor{proofc}{fg=black}
%\setbeamercolor{proofe}{fg=black}
%\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\large,font=\scshape}
        
%\setbeamertemplate{theorem}[ams style]
%\setbeamertemplate{figures}[numbered]
        
\setbeamertemplate{theorem}[ams style]
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\makeatletter
\ifbeamer@countsect
\newtheorem{theorem}{\translate{Theorem}}[section]
\else
\newtheorem{theorem}{\translate{Theorem}}[section]
\fi
\newtheorem{corollary}{\translate{Corollary}}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{\translate{Lemma}}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{\translate{Proposition}}
\newtheorem{problem}{\translate{Problem}}
\newtheorem{solution}{\translate{Solution}}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{\translate{Definition}}
\newtheorem{definitions}[theorem]{\translate{Definitions}}


\newtheorem*{exc}{\translate{Exercise}}
\newtheorem*{excs}{\translate{Exercises}}


\newenvironment{lem}{\begin{lemma}}{\end{lemma}}
\newenvironment{thm}{\begin{theorem}}{\end{theorem}}
\newenvironment{cor}{\begin{corollary}}{\end{corollary}}
\newenvironment{defn}{\begin{definition}}{\end{definition}}
\newenvironment{prop}{\begin{proposition}}{\end{proposition}}
\makeatother


\makeatletter
\def\th@myexmpstyle{%
    \small % body font
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=magenta,bg=black}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=lime,bg=black}
    \def\inserttheoremblockenv{block}
}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{myexmpstyle}
\newtheorem*{example}{\translate{Example:}}
\newtheorem*{examples}{\translate{Examples:}}



\makeatletter
\def\th@mystyle{%
    \normalfont % body font
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=black, fg=cyan!40!white}
    \def\inserttheoremblockenv{block}
}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem*{Rem}{Remark:}
\newtheorem*{rems}{Remarks:}

\newenvironment*{Exmps}
{
    \begin{examples}\parskip 1ex
        \vspace{-1ex}\footnotesize
        \begin{enumerate}%[label=\arabic*.]
        }
        {
        \end{enumerate}\normalsize
    \end{examples}  
}

\newenvironment*{exercises}
{
    \footnotesize
    \begin{excs}\
        \vspace{-1ex}
        \begin{enumerate}%[label=\arabic*.]
        }
        {
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{excs}
    \normalsize
}

\newenvironment*{exmp}{\begin{example}\parskip 1ex \footnotesize}{\end{example}\normalsize}
\newenvironment*{exercise}{\begin{exc}\footnotesize}{\end{exc}\normalsize}


\newenvironment{rem}{\begin{Rem}\parskip 1ex \vspace{-2ex}\footnotesize}{\end{Rem}\normalsize}

\newenvironment{Rems}
{
    
    \begin{rems}
        \vspace{-1ex}\footnotesize
        \begin{enumerate}%[label=(\alph*)]
        }
        {
        \end{enumerate}\normalsize
    \end{rems}  
}

%\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup
{
    colorlinks=true, %set true if you want colored links
    %   linktoc=all,     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
    linkcolor=black,  %choose some color if you want links to stand out
    citecolor=teal,
}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{prop}{proposition}{propositions}
\crefname{proposition}{proposition}{propositions}

\crefname{lemma}{lemma}{lemmas}
\crefname{lem}{lemma}{lemmas}
\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}
%\newcommand{\myref}[1]{\beamergotobutton{\cref{#1}}}
\newcommand{\link}[2]{\hyperlink{#1}{\beamerbutton{#2}}}
%       \newcommand{\Label}[1]{\hypertarget<.>{label#1}{}}


\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}


\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}
\parskip 1ex
%
%
%
\begin{document}
    
    \makeatletter
    \def\stringpleasehidethistitle{{please hide this title\ifnum\beamer@autobreakcount>0\relax{}\space\usebeamertemplate*{frametitle continuation}\fi}}
    \defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{only sub}[1][left]
    {
        \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
        \@tempdima=\textwidth%
        \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
        \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,#1,wd=\the\@tempdima]{frametitle}
            \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
            \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
            \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fte#1\endcsname\fi%
            \ifx\insertframetitle\stringpleasehidethistitle%   check if magic word presents
            \else%                                             check if magic word presents
            \strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%               check if magic word presents
            \fi%                                               check if magic word presents
            {%
                \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
                \else%
                {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
                \fi
            }%
            \vskip-1ex%
            \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }
    
    \begin{frame}
        $ a^{\prime} $\\ % WORKS!
        $ a' $ % DOES NOT WORK!
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since $a'$ is working in plain beamer without modifications, could you narrow down your extensive code example to the modification that causes the error?

Comment: I am sorry but I do not know which part of the preamble is causing the problem.

Comment: Then I highly suggest you try to figure it out by selectively commenting out parts of the preamble in order to specify your question. I doubt that many people are willing to that for you seeing as you used a lot of custom modificiations.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your suggestion. That is my last resort and will do that at the end. But I posted this problem in this forum hoping to get some help about modification of which portion (size or color or any particular block style) may lead to this problem.

Comment: really it is your responsibility to cut down the example, you can't expect people to want to do that part removing unnecessary code that you have posted.

Comment: Do you need `hanging` in `beamer`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the `hanging` package. See [hanging package chokes on apostrophes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61732/hanging-package-chokes-on-apostrophes) for a solution.

I figured this out by noting the error that was occurring when running your document:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
'->\futurelet 
              \next \h@ngrqtest 
l.422     \end{frame}
```

Noting that `\h@ngrqtest` was the problem, I googled that (originally just to see what the offending package was) and turned up the error that you encountered.